# Python 33 windows: Changing the GUI icon

Tags: python, tkinter

I am quite new to Python, so I've got Python 33 on Windows Vista. I am trying to change the icon of my text editor program. This is the script I am using:

```
def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    root.wm_iconbitmap('txteditor.ico')  # Saved this in C:/Python33/DLLs
    app = txtEditor(root)                # I've classed this 
    root.mainloop()
```

I keep on getting this error, though:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Python Code\myTxtEditor.py", line 96, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Python Code\myTxtEditor.py", line 90, in main
    root.wm_iconbitmap('txteditor.ico')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1648, in wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "txteditor.ico" not defined
```

I've searched a lot for an answer, but nothing ever seems to fit my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There must be an error with the path that you are giving to python for the icon.
A: Check that you gave the full path from C:/
B: Make sure that you have exactly the right filename and directory

This should stop the error

Comment: Nope:_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "C:/Python33/DLLs/txteditor.ico" not defined

Comment: Hmm. then I am sorry I have no idea what is wrong. This code (ish) works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the icon is not in the current working directory, nor in a path that you have defined. You should define the full path like this:

```
def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    root.wm_iconbitmap(r'c:/Python33/DLLs/txteditor.ico')
    app = txtEditor(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

The key thing here is to use a **raw** string. That should now work.

Comment: Still nothing:_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "C:/Python33/DLLs/txteditor.ico" not defined